# How does `supervisorctl tail` work, for a given process?

Tags: logging, supervisord

Where does `supervisorctl tail` take the log information of a certain process from? How do I get a full log?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the command line help (`supervisorctl help tail`):

```
tail [-f] <name> [stdout|stderr] (default stdout)
Ex:
tail -f <name>          Continuous tail of named process stdout
                        Ctrl-C to exit.
tail -100 <name>        last 100 *bytes* of process stdout
tail <name> stderr      last 1600 *bytes* of process stderr
```

So by default, the `tail` command tails the process stdout. If you need to get the full log, the [`stdout_logfile` option of the `[program:x]` section](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-values) determines where that is stored; there is a `stderr_logfile` option as well.

If that option is not set or set to `AUTO`, a logfile will be created when the process starts, but cleaned up whenever supervisord restarts. This file is created in the directory set by [the `[supervisord]` `childlogdir` option](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-values) (which is your platform's [`TMP` directory](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) by default), and have a generated filename of the form `<program-name>-<stdout|stderr>---<supervisor-identifier>-<6-random-characters>.log`, e.g. `varnish-stdout---supervisor-AqY52e.log`.

Thus, if you want to access the whole stdout log, you need to at the very least set the `childlogdir` option to a fixed directory to save you from having to search for the right temporary directory.